# using global variable in python among modules in different packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I'm new to Python and am trying to use a global counter from a module in a package in different modules in different packages. What I want to do is declare a variable in a module and import it to other modules in different packages. I made a simple test for the question and it's happening here too. I made all files in a same directory(they are now in the same package but the problem is the same).

file glbcntmod.py :

```
glbcnt = 0
```

file glbfuncmod.py :

```
from glbcntmod import glbcnt
def glbfunc():
    global glbcnt
    print 'glbcnt = ',glbcnt
```

file : test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from glbcntmod import glbcnt
from glbfuncmod import glbfunc

loccnt = 0
def localfunc():
    print 'loccnt = ',loccnt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glbcnt = 0
    for i in xrange(0,4):
        glbfunc()
        localfunc()
        glbcnt += 1
        loccnt += 1
```

When I run test.py, the result is like below. loccnt is incrementing but glbcnt is always 0. What is the problem?

```
glbcnt =  0
loccnt =  0
glbcnt =  0
loccnt =  1
glbcnt =  0
loccnt =  2
glbcnt =  0
loccnt =  3
```

Comment: Why do you have `glbcnt = 0` in test.py ?

Comment: You could consider using a distributed key/value storage a la redis.https://redislabs.com/ebook/redis-in-action/part-2-core-concepts-2/chapter-5-using-redis-for-application-support/5-2-counters-and-statistics/5-2-1-storing-counters-in-redis

Comment: @polku just a mistake. if I remove it, it's the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to keep the module where the variable is as a reference:

```
import other_module

other_module.counter += 1
```

If you do that everywhere you use `counter` it will have a consitent value across modules.

That happens because each time you do an assignment to a name in Python, the object associated with that name changes -

That is,  if you do

```
from othermodule import counter
counter = 1
```

Your `counter` variable will point to a different object from that assignment on.  And since numbers are immutable objects, there are even other problems with that.

But f you keep the original module around, you are changing an attribute in that module object - which behaves exactly like any other Python object. As long as other code access the variable as an attribute of the module, you are good.

Comment: ok, I understand it. import module and use module.variable format. It sounds like when we import a module, the id of the object is not changed, but when we import a variable from a module, it is a new object. that when the object is immutable. is it kind of like this?

Comment: Almost -when you import a variable form a  module, it is still the same object - if it is mutable (like a list), changing it will be reflected on other modules. But whenver you assign that variable to something (`=` operator, or `+=` and others on imutable objects), that variable points to a new object - unrelated to the original module.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `int` is immutable in python. That means doing something like

```
a = 0
b = a  # b = 0
b += 1  # b = 2
```

will still leave `a` as `0`.

When you do `from glbcntmod import glbcnt`, this basically equals

```
import glbcntmod
glbcnt = glbcntmod.glbcnt
```

So, if you then increment `glbcnt`, only the local name will be assigned the new value. The original `glbcnt` is not changed.

If you want to use a global variable, you must use its global name. So what you want to work with and modify is `glbcntmod.glbcnt`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to update a global variable from another module, check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595447/3224629

Answer (score 2):

In test.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    glbcnt = 0
    for i in xrange(0,4):
        ...
        glbcnt += 1
```

You make a local glbcnt variable here, which is the one that gets incremented. Your glbfunc() does not see this variable and thus cannot print its value.

Try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    global glbcnt
    glbcnt = 0
    ...
```

Also, because of this, your entire glbcntmod.py file becomes pointless.

It's not because a variable is declared global once, that it becomes global everywhere.

"global glbcnt" simply means that from here on, in this scope, any references to glbcnt will refer to the global variable. No effects whatsoever are applied to other scopes, ie. other modules.

Comment: You seem right but when I add 'global globcnt' in main, it's the same..strange.. Of course I removed 'glbcnt = 0' too from main.

Comment: Hi, now I understand it from bueno's reply. To add, I originally used 'global glbcnt' in every function before I assign to glbcnt but the thing is when I import a variable from a module, it is imported from 'the global value' and when I declare 'global glbcnt' inside the function, it means 'use the imported global value glbcnt(but _it's still local_). So in this case I shoudl use import module.variable format. That's how I understand it.