# Global variables scope in modules

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

Following are my files and output. All I want to do is get Value of `x` after `func1()` as `20`. [I have already referred to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595393/python-global-variable-scoping). I want to know why this do not work? Is it necessary to use `import globalVar` instead of `from globalVar import *`

globalVar.py

```
#globalVar.py
x=10
```

fun1.py

```
from globalVar import *

def func1():
    global x
    x=20
    print("X in fun1",x)
```

main.py

```
from fun1 import *
from globalVar import *

print("X before fun1=",x)
func1()
print("X after fun1=",x)
```

Output:

```
X before fun1= 10  
X in fun1 20  
X after fun1= 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

**Try This:**

**GlobalVar.py:**

```
global x
x = 10
```

**fun1.py:**

```
import GlobalVar

def func1():
    GlobalVar.x = 20
    print("X in fun1", GlobalVar.x)
```

**main.py:**

```
from fun1 import *
from GlobalVar import *

print("X before fun1=", GlobalVar.x)
func1()
print("X after fun1=", GlobalVar.x)
```

Check this this will give you your desired output according to your question.

Hope this will help you! Thankyou! :)

**Note:** The globals table dictionary is the dictionary of the current module (inside a function, this is a module where it is defined, not the module where it is called)

Comment: This doesn't really explain _why_.

Comment: @Nae: What you want to understand ? if it is about global variable or why i do this read [this](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html)

Comment: @MayureshSardar : Yes previous answer is not giving your desired output i have now updated the answer check the updated one. Thankyou :)

Comment: @MayureshSardar: Updated/Edited answer is giving your desired ouput

Comment: @Nae: It will not raise any error beacause i checked it myself. And about why the answer is The globals table dictionary is the dictionary of the current module (inside a function, this is a module where it is defined, not the module where it is called). and in this case he is calling a module where he define his global variable, in calling and getting the value it is fine but when changing it you must explicitly need to define that you are change the value of global defined in your other module thats why i do like this (GlobalVar.x) as you can see in updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this does not work is that
The fun1() method call in main.py doesn't return the updated value of x ie 20.
which is why the scope of updated x is only in fun1 once the execution is over, the value is lost & when you print the value of x the third time it simply refers back to the global variable

Heres what you may do to make it work
1.fun1.py

```
from globalVar import *

def func1():
    global x
    x=20
    print("X in fun1",x)
    return x //here it returns the value of 20 to be found later
```

2.globalVar.py

```
x=10
```

3.main.py

```
from fun1 import *

print("X before fun1=",x)
x = func1()//here the updated value of x is retrived and updated, had you not done this the scope of x=20 would only be within the func1()
print("X after fun1=",x)
```