# scope of global variables in modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, global-variables

**Summary:**

Depending on how a function is defined - wether locally or in a module, and how the module is imported - the scope of global variables differs. i) I would like to understand this and ii) I am looking for a way to have the scope of some variables defined within a module to be global to the entire process.

**To illustrate the problem:**

1) Create a module named MyModule.py with this content:

```
def MyFunctionInModule():
    global gvar2
    gvar2 = "global var 2"
    print gvar2 + " from MyFunctionInModule"
    print gvar3 + " from MyFunctionInModule"
    return
```

and drop it in a module search path.

2) At the Python interpreter prompt enter this:

```
def MyFunction():
    global gvar1
    gvar1 = "global var 1"
    print gvar1 + " from MyFunctionInModule"
    print gvar3 + " from MyFunctionInModule"
    return

global gvar3
gvar3 = "global var 3"
```

(a) This works as I expect (i.e. gvar1 and gvar3 are visible everywhere):

```
MyFunction()
print gvar1 + " at prompt"
```

for which the results are:

```
>>> MyFunction()  
global var 1 from MyFunctionInModule  
global var 3 from MyFunctionInModule  
>>> print gvar1 + " at prompt"  
global var 1 at prompt
```

(b) But this doesn't work:

```
import MyModule
MyModule.MyFunctionInModule() # gvar3 is not defined
print gvar2 + " at prompt" # gvar2 is not defined
```

for which the results are:

```
>>> MyModule.MyFunctionInModule() # gvar3 is not defined
global var 2 from MyFunctionInModule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MyModule.py", line 5, in MyFunctionInModule
    print gvar3 + " from MyFunctionInModule"
NameError: global name 'gvar3' is not defined
>>> print gvar2 + " at prompt" # gvar2 is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'gvar2' is not defined
```

(c) Neither does this but to a lesser level (i.e. gvar2 becomes visible):

```
from MyModule import *
MyFunctionInModule() # gvar3 is not defined
print gvar2 + " at prompt"
```

for which the results are:

```
>>> MyFunctionInModule() # gvar3 is not defined
global var 2 from MyFunctionInModule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MyModule.py", line 5, in MyFunctionInModule
    print gvar3 + " from MyFunctionInModule"
NameError: global name 'gvar3' is not defined
>>> print gvar2 + " at prompt"
global var 2 at prompt
```

**Questions:**

Could anyone explain (or provide links to good documentation explaining) why there are such differences in behaviour between (a), (b) and (c)?

What should be done to obtain the same behaviour with (b) and (c) as with (a)?

**Some related topics** (but not fully covering my needs):
[Global variables scope in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123982/global-variables-scope-in-modules)
[Python global variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595393/python-global-variable-scoping)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

execfile() does exactly the job but I am not sure it can be considered as good practice:

```
execfile("MyModule.py")
global gvar3
gvar3 = "global var 3"
MyFunctionInModule()
print gvar2 + " at prompt"
```

For which the results are:

```
>>> MyFunctionInModule()
global var 2 from MyFunctionInModule
global var 3 from MyFunctionInModule
>>> print gvar2 + " at prompt"
global var 2 at prompt
```